# UI onPress freezes for 2-3 seconds when performing dispatch onRefresh FlatList (React Native)

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a Flatlist and three Tabs. When I pull to refresh the FlatList data (it is a dispatch which under hood performs GET all items from server then write them in Realm DB of the APP. The action is performed using Saga) UI onPress freezes for 2-3 seconds. When I press on tabs or on any list item they react only after 2-3 seconds. Performance monitor shows JS: -2.1 fps at that time. This only happens on Android devices. iOS works smoothly.

This is my FlameGraph and it seems that VirtualizedList (FlatList) needs optimization
[image]

```
const renderItem = useCallback(
    ({ item }) => {
      return <ListItem item={item} showPriority onPress={onPress} />;
    },
    [onPress],
  );

 <FlatList
          data={data}
          renderItem={renderItem}
          keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
          refreshControl={<RefreshControl {...refreshControlProps} />}
        />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a lot of rerenders which happen on JS side.

First, you need to detect it. Using flipper and flame graph you can check it.
https://fbflipper.com/docs/features/react-native/
[image]

Second, when you detect a problem try to apply optimizations for FlatLists from the official documentation: https://reactnative.dev/docs/optimizing-flatlist-configuration

Comment: Kirill, I added my FlameGraph, it seems that Flatlist needs optimization

Comment: you can check why your list render in right side and you can add your flatlist code in a question